# how to change auto layout constraints after add

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios8

I know to change auto layout constraints with `IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint * xyz;`

I am doing with this code:

**Add** constraints with this code

```
NSLayoutConstraint *btnbottomConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: currentview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:1.0f constant:sheight];
        [supperView addConstraint:btnbottomConstraint];
```

**Get** constraints with this code

```
NSArray * arrConstarint=btnSubbmit.constraints;
for (NSLayoutConstraint * constraint in arrConstarint)
{
    if (constraint.firstAttribute==NSLayoutAttributeHeight)
    {
        constraint.constant=self.maxHeight;
    }
    else if (constraint.firstAttribute==NSLayoutAttributeWidth)
    {
        constraint.constant=self.maxWidth;
    }
}
```

when i get constraints of view then **arrConstarint.count** is 0,
please help me where i wrong.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
[supperView addConstraint:btnbottomConstraint];
```

to

```
[currentView addConstraint:btnbottomConstraint];
```

height and width will be added to view not with respect to superview.
Let me know if it you need further help